# Storing and using encryption key without user input in python

Tags: python, encryption, key

I am writing a script that is going to be ran as a scheduled task every morning. The program pulls encrypted usernames and passwords from a SQL Database and will need to decrypt them. My question is, is there any way for me to store the encryption/decryption key for the script to use without expecting a user input such as a password? Ideally the script should run completely autonomously.

Comment: Could you please rephrase the question.

Comment: Have you tried using environment variables?

Answer (score 0):

The most flexible idea as stated by @EugeneProut would be to use env variable. I would like to extend that it also provides the best security. Then You can simply access the variable by using the code as below:

```
import os
print(os.environ['ENCRYPTION_KEY'])
```

This solution is the most production-like, since gives the best possibility to provide the key securely for example as secret.